# Is there a function in python to get the size of an arbitrary precision number?

Tags: python, arbitrary-precision

I'm working on a cryptographic scheme in python, so I use arbitrary precision numbers (`long`) all the time. I'm using python 2.7.

My problem is that I need to get the most significant two bytes (16 bits) of a number and check if they are the padding I inserted. I've tried `sys.getsizeof()` but that gives the size of the entire object and guess I could also iterate through every few bits of the number until there are only two bytes left, but is there a more pythonian way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "the first two bytes (16 bits)" do you mean the most significant or least significant bits?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I edited the question to address this. I meant most significant.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you:

```
>>> n = 1 << 1000
>>> n.bit_length()
1001
>>> n >> (n.bit_length() - 16)
32768L
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `long.bit_length()`. E.g.:

```
% long.bit_length(1024L)
11
```

Or:

```
% 1024L.bit_length()
11
```

To get the first 2 bytes, assuming "first" means "least significant", use modulo 16:

```
x = 123456789
x % 2**16
52501
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I meant most significant. I edited the question to reflect that. Thanks anyway!